# How to keep attribute after reduce?

Tags: scala, akka-stream

Using below code I'm attempting to output the name and the sum of the ages for each person :

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Sink, Source}

object CalculateMeanInStream extends App {

  implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()

  case class Person(name: String, age: Double)
  val personSource = Source(List(Person("1", 30),Person("1", 20),Person("1", 20),Person("1", 30),Person("2", 2)))
  val meanPrintSink = Sink.foreach[Double](println)
  val printSink = Sink.foreach[Double](println)

  def calculateMean(values: List[Double]): Double = {
    values.sum / values.size
  }

  personSource.groupBy(maxSubstreams = 2 , s  => s.name)
    .map(m => m.age)
    .reduce(_ + _ )
    .mergeSubstreams
    .runForeach(println)

}
```

The output is :

```
2.0
100.0
```

Is there a way to keep the persons name as part of the reduce so that the following is produced in the output :

```
(2.0 , 2)
(100.0 , 1)
```

I've tried :

```
  personSource.groupBy(maxSubstreams = 2 , s  => s.name)
    .reduce((x , y) => x.age + y.age)
    .mergeSubstreams
    .runForeach(println)
```

but throws compiler error :

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Double
 required: CalculateMeanInStream.Person
    .reduce((x , y) => x.age + y.age)
```

Comment: @GaëlJ yes, but what type of reduce function ? signature of reduce is 'def reduce[T >: Out](f: (T, T) => T): Repr[T] = via(new Reduce[T](f))' so I cannot change the result type, from the type signature I need to produce a Person instead of Double.

Comment: Sorry, read too fast. I posted an answer.

Comment: This seems like a weird use case for a stream based solution. This is just not a problem which should be solved with streams. Are you doing this for learning Akka, or is it a sample problem for a similar problem statement ?

Comment: @sarveshseri ultimately I want to monitor volatility in stream, I'm beginning with a sum function to simplify. It's for learning Akka and a potential use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```scala
personSource
    .groupBy(maxSubstreams = 2, s => s.name)
    .reduce((person1, person2) => Person(person1.name, person1.age + person2.age))
    .mergeSubstreams
    .runForeach(println)
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be a more elegant way but I'd do it like this:

```scala
personSource
    .groupBy(maxSubstreams = 2, s => s.name)
    .map(x => x.name -> x.age)
    .reduce { case ((a, b) , (_, d)) => (a, b + d) }
    .mergeSubstreams
    .runForeach(println)
```

Comment: thanks but that fails to compile : 
not a legal formal parameter.
Note: Tuples cannot be directly destructured in method or function parameters.
      Either create a single parameter accepting the Tuple2,
      or consider a pattern matching anonymous function: `{ case (a, b) => ... }
    .reduce(((a, b) , (_, d)) => (a, b + d))

Comment: Do as suggested by the compilation error :)

Comment: I receive this error : "missing parameter type for expanded function
The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: (?, ?) => ?
    .reduce { case ((a : String, b : Double) , (c : String, d : Double)) => (a, b + d) }"

I tried updating with : ".reduce { case ((a : String, b : Double) , (c : String, d : Double)) => (a, b + d) }" but same error

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fold()`, [which](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Sink/fold.html#signature) would let you skip the map. Instead of the map and reduce lines.

Just write as follows:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Sink, Source}

object CalculateMeanInStream extends App {

  implicit val actorSystem: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()

  case class Person(name: String, age: Double)
  val personSource = Source(List(Person("1", 30),Person("1", 20),Person("1", 20),Person("1", 30),Person("2", 2)))
  val meanPrintSink = Sink.foreach[Double](println)
  val printSink = Sink.foreach[Double](println)

  def calculateMean(values: List[Double]): Double = {
    values.sum / values.size
  }

  val reducer: ((String, Double), (String, Double)) => (String, Double) = 
    (person, accPerson) => (person._1, person._2 + accPerson._2)

  personSource.groupBy(maxSubstreams = 2 , s  => s.name)
    .fold((0D, "")){ case ((sum, _), x) => (sum + x.age, x.name )}
    .mergeSubstreams
    .runForeach(println)
    .onComplete(_ => actorSystem.terminate())(actorSystem.dispatcher)

}
```

Your output will be:

```
(2.0, 2)
(100.0, 1)
```

as you need per requirements.